# Unable to install pal2nal package in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, bioinformatics

I am new here and also just learning how to work in anaconda, so I would like to ask for help. I need some packages installed to be able to run my sequence analysis and calculate dN/dS ratio. For that I need paml, clustal omega, prank, blast and pal2nal packages to be installed. I'm working in Windows 10 (unfortunately, but no other way - working laptop).

I have been trying to install pal2nal package in anaconda using conda, bioconda, pip commands and I always get the same error.

My tries:  conda install -c bioconda pal2nal, conda install -c anaconda pal2nal, conda install pal2nal, pip install pal2nal (it doesn't exist among python packages) and I even tried to create a new environment and install it there but no luck. It's the same with the rest of the packages.

The message what I always get is:
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError:

Does anyone know why I always get this error and maybe what to do to be able to install these packages?

Thank you very much for help!!

Comment: Have you tried installation in a new environment?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but that package is only available through Bioconda and Bioconda does not support Windows natively.

[image]

Instead, you will need to work with a virtualization or containerization layer such as WSL or Docker/Singularity.